# Flash android tablet with custom GUI made by using c / c++ like emwin QT

Tags: c++, c, qt, embedded, stm32

I have a question i came across embedded software development. I can programme gui and flash Arm Cortex m3/m4 proceesors with spi I2c uart bus interfaces. I can make decent gui on it using libraries like qt or emwin.

My question is can i flash android tablet with my own gui  on it. I mean i dont want android os on my tablet. Can i flash my own custom firmware on android tablet. Where do i get the schematic of those tablets and is there any project on web like this.

Please dont put comments like why you want to do it. My question is simple can i / we do it if yes than how please.

Thank You !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get is running `PostmarketOS`, which is Linux Distribution with GNU userland for Android Devices. 
Developing a custom firmware is hardwork. Checkout the PostmarketOS website for the list of devices Compatible.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but i want to do everything from scratch like you do on stm32 or nxp boards and i can use small os like freertos. I dont want to use any sort of linux with it.

Comment: @Mandeep the Android tablet is not small simply because of the fact that it runs android. It has much more peripherals than you overage microcontroller but no documented interface to use them besides drivers found in Android/linux (which might be closed source). What you want is likely possible, but would require enough knowledge and skill to consider if it's worth it. Also, it highly depends on the device you have so there is no general advice to give here.

Comment: @DanM. So what is the another possibility if I want to make my own tablet from scratch. Is there any project for that ???

Comment: @Mandeep you can, it's just harder than dealing with simple controllers. It also depends on what you mean by "your own" tablet. You can "build" one from available components/order small batch from a factory. You can use an existing one and flash it with different OS (if available). You could attempt to write your own OS or maybe port some other existing OS but it takes a lot of experience and time. If you want to just blink some LEDs it can possibly be done relatively easy if you find all the datasheets for your HW, but it's not really "intended purpose".